# How can PowerBuilder connect to a REST API?

Tags: rest, powerbuilder

I am using [Sybase PowerBuilder 11.5](http://infocenter-archive.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.pb_11.5/title.htm) to develop a BS structure software, now I want to use PowerBuilder to connect a REST API. Specifically, I want to use PowerBuilder to get data from:

http://172.16.0.14:30201/childTable?groupId=SNS16495&dictCode=02001

This REST service returns the data I want from the server, how can I make PowerBuilder retrieve data from this service?

Comment: You might be able to use Ronald Smith's WinHTTP to do it.http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_winhttp.html

Comment: Google "PowerBuilder REST API" to find a lot of information.

Comment: Please add an example output because your link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

PowerBuilder 11.5 is extremely old and doesn't support calling REST Web APIs.  There might be some third party DLLs you could include to enable this, but the current version of PowerBuilder (version 2017) natively provides a new HTTPClient object together with JSON Parser and Generator objects so you can easily call REST Web APIs.  In terms of security, it supports TLS 1.2, provides OAuth client plus encryption, hashing, and encoding functions.

Comment: I hear the new 2018 Appeon PowerBuilder will handle the REST/JSON as a datawindow data source. Nice.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  Actually, PowerBuilder 2017 already allows DataWindows to have REST/JSON Web API as its data source.  What PowerBuilder 2018 adds is the ability to create the REST/JSON APIs (in C# and with DataWindow technology) that feed the client-side DataWindows.

Comment: now , i used the "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0" to parse the json on power builder 11.5. and it works well yet. thank all of you.